# Is there a Perl module that validates an XML against a schema?

Tags: xml, perl, validation, schema

I need to validate an XML agaist a schema.

I tried XML::SAX::ParserFactory; XML::Validator::Schema and related modules but looks like they are limited.
Limited in the sense that it didn't recognize schema elements such as xsd:unique, xsd:group, xsd:keyref, xsd:union and xsd:key.

Are these xsd:unique, etc. new additions?

Appreciate if you can point me to some Perl modules which are upto date and upto the task.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried validating it with xmllint?

Comment: Command line tool of xmllint works very well.  
Thanks JDrago!

Answer (score 10):

Have a look at [XML::LibXML](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-LibXML/)

This uses the highly regarded libxml2 library which most people cite as a successor to Expat and [XML::Parser](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Parser/) based modules.

For schema validation look at [XML::LibXML::Schema](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/XML::LibXML::Schema)

```
use XML::LibXML;
use XML::LibXML::Schema;

my $schema = XML::LibXML::Schema->new(location => 'file.xsd' );
my $parser = XML::LibXML->new;

my $xml    = 'file.xml';
my $doc    = $parser->parse_file( $xml );

eval { $schema->validate( $doc ) };
die $@ if $@;

say "$xml is valid\n";
```

NB. I still mainly a [XML::Twig](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Twig/) user and barely touch XML schema so I don't know if XML::LibXML::Schema will solve the problem you have but it possibly is the best solution on CPAN for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

@Thushan
Is it absolutely necessary for you to use Perl? If not, why not give a try to **XMLSTARLET**? It's a quite nice toolkit for manipulating XMLs in a terminal!

It supports not just legacy DTDs and the XSD as you need, also it supports Relax-NG schemas. Check it's documentation to learn how to [Validate XML Documents with xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html#d0e520)
I hope this helps you ;)

Have a good day!

PD Oh I see you used xmllint! It's great too, but I prefer xmlstarlet =) Give it a try ;)

Comment: The nice thing about `xmllint` is that it uses the same library as XML::LibXML so when I want to do something more complicated than a single `xmllint` command I can easily switch to Perl.  I use `xmlstarlet` for simple XML transformations.